# How does Cocos2d-x keep code (C++ file) safe from decompilation?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I just decompiled APK using dex2jar and JD-GUI to access the source code, but I could not find any `.h` or `.cpp` files in `classes.dex` folder. I want to know how does Cocos2d-x take care of that issue and where are all these files stored?

Answer (score 1):

the c++ files are compiled into a dynamic library, in lib/armeabi/, like libxxx.so

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I also want to know that is there any way to access those c++ files from apk?